# What is the point of the ILoggingBuilder interface in ASP.NET Core?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I looked inside the the built in `WebApplicationBuilder` class and noticed the

```
public ILoggingBuilder Logging { get; }
```

property. Here is the entire `ILoggingBuilder` interface:

```
public interface ILoggingBuilder
{
    IServiceCollection Services { get; }
}
```

It just stores a single property so what is the point of this interface? Couldn't the `WebApplicationBuilder` just store an instance of `IServiceCollection` directly?

Comment: Because There are many built-in Extension Methods about this interface, You can easily use these Extension Methods to configure your log system.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's about scoping and reducing intellisense hell. If everything was on IServiceCollection it would get cluttered quickly. Subsystems that are highly configurable and are themselves extensible need a "target" to extend. This is one of the patterns the platform employs to solve this problem.

Some of the patterns you'll see:

Simple options via a callback:

```
services.AddComponent((ComponentOptions options) => 
{
    options.SomeFlag = true;
});
```

This pattern works well when the number of options on component is small, self-contained and has limited extensibility.

Complex builder returned from the API:

```
IComponentBuilder builder = services.AddComponent();

builder.AddExtensibleThing1();
builder.AddExtensibleThing2();
```

Breaks the fluent API pattern but reduces nested lambdas.

OR

```
services.AddComponent((IComponentBuilder builder) =>
{
    builder.AddExtensibleThing1();
    builder.AddExtensibleThing2();
});
```

Similar to the above but nested instead of a return value. Keeps the fluent API working at the cost of more callbacks.

Answer (score 1):

I looked at the documentation for the [ILoggingBuilder](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.logging.iloggingbuilder?view=dotnet-plat-ext-8.0), and it states:

> An interface for configuring logging providers.

And yes, it has only one property, but many extension methods are written for `ILoggingBuilder`, so indeed, this interface is for configuring logging providers.